# авторизованный юзер не мог зайти на страницу авторизации

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

Мне нужно, что бы авторизованный юзер не мог зайти на страницу авторизации и при попытке его кидало в кабинет. Сначало налепил костылей в контроллере, а потом подумал о security и добавил там вот это

```
 - { path: ^/fuck, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Правильно ли я понимаю, что если юзер авторизован его туда пускать не должно? Вообщем не пашет, дайте хлебных крошек куда идти плиз.

Comment: По идее в модуле авторизации должна быть проверка, если юзер уже авторизован - редирект куда нужно. Иначе делаем нужные проверки. Но это не точно

Comment: Вы поставили ответу галочку решения. Вы реально решили вопрос ? Мне что то подсказывает что нет :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как Security достаточно сложный механизм для понимания. Рекомендую прочесть введение в security на [русском](https://symfony.com.ua/doc/current/security.html). По Вашему кейсу скажу, что вероятно Вам нужно построить [традиционную форму входа в систему](https://symfony.com.ua/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html).

Но перед тем как реализовывать "сложный" механизм входа потренеруйтесь на "легком".

Итак, у вас уже есть [Конфигурирование аутентификации ваших пользователей](https://symfony.com.ua/doc/current/security.html#a) и, следующим шагом, Вам нужно добавить [Конфигурирование загрузки пользователей](https://symfony.com.ua/doc/current/security.html#b). Для этого нужно добавить провайдера пользователя - это сервис либо описание ролей пользователя, в простой конфигурации нужно просто описать юзеров, записав роль и пароль. Так же необходимо добавить тип энкодинга, в нашем случае это plaintext

## config/packages/security.yaml

```
security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    admin:
                        password: somepass
                        roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN'

    # ...
```

Мы настроили провайдер и теперь переходим к авторизации, то есть нам нужно запреnить доступ, и самый простой способ это тот, который сейчас написан у Вас. В `access_control` просто добавить

```
- { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
- { path: ^/profile, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

то при неудачной авторизации будет возвращаться 403.

Для того что бы редиректить на определенный урл отправляется в раздел [Как построить традиционную форму входа в систему](https://symfony.com.ua/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html).

И там описано, что нужно описать `login_path` и `check_path`

## app/config/security.yml

```
security:
    # ...

    firewalls:
        main:
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                login_path: /some/login
                check_path: some/login
```

А далее уже действуем по [примеру](https://symfony.com.ua/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html) и в *контроллере где акшн логина* необходимо добавить логику авторизации.

## src/AppBundle/Controller/SecurityController.php

```
public function loginAction(Request $request, AuthenticationUtils $authUtils)
{
    $error = $authUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

    $lastUsername = $authUtils->getLastUsername();

    return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', array(
        'last_username' => $lastUsername,
        'error'         => $error,
    ));
}
```

---

## [Authorization Checker](https://symfony.com.ua/doc/current/security.html#security-securing-controller-ru)

Так же Вы можете реализовать проверку роли используя [Authorization Checker](https://symfony.com.ua/doc/current/security.html#security-securing-controller-ru).
И в контроллере Вы проверяете

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $isUserAnonymous = $this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY');
   
    if ( $isUserAnonymous) {
         return $this->redirectToRoute('profile');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Решение вопроса не очень сложное. 
Согласно документации, а именно вот здесь - https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html

мы находим вот эту "роль"

> IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED: All logged in users have this, even if
>   they are logged in because of a "remember me cookie". Even if you
>   don't use the remember me functionality, you can use this to check if
>   the user is logged in.

тут если что то не понятно, то речь идет о том что данная "роль" имеется у всех аунтифицированных пользователей, а это значит уже пол победы!

А вторую половину победы можно обеспечить двумя вариантами.

1. Не правильный! (но имеющий право на жизнь) . Вы создаете EventListener ... (тут я забыл на какое именно событие его вешать и решил что не буду продолжать).
2. Правильное. Вы делаете "свою" форму авторизации как в документации, а по сути расширяете существующую добавляя нужный контроллер (смотрим вот сюда https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup) и в силу того что он наследует базовый контроллер то вы проверяете в методе login пользователя на роль IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED и если да - редиректите на нужный вам роут.

Простите что не очень подробно, мне показалось что вы поймете о чем я.